# How to import .OUT file into R?

Tags: r

I have a file with the extension of .OUT; I can't seem to get it into R with its original column separations preserved.

Is there anyway I can read it into R without compromising its columns and rows?

The file can be found here: http://www.repeatmasker.org/PreMaskedGenomes.html ("hg19.fa.out.gz", the first one)

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of different compilers and programs can create .out files of different formats, so it's going to depend on what created it. Also, note that your file is compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using the read.fwf function:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html

```
positions <- c(5,11,16,21,34,42,49,60,62,77,97,106,110,117)
widths <- diff(positions)
read.fwf(file='hg19.fa.out', widths=widths)
```

You may have to play with these (example) numbers until you can read in with no truncations.

(Another option is to read it into excel using the fixed width option, export to csv, then read into R via read.csv)